# sql statement in access that group items and count their sum

Tags: ms-access

I would like to write an sql statement in microsoft access that group items and count their sum

My table is like below :

```
id : Auto-Increment
Items : String
Quantity : Number
```

Eg :

```
id | Items | Quantity
1 | A | 10
2 | B | 5
3 | A | 10
4 | C | 20
5 | C | 20
6 | A | 10
7 | C | 20
8 | B | 5
9 | B | 5
```

Expected result is

```
id | Items | Quantity
1 | A | 30
2 | B | 15
3 | C | 60
```

Comment: How are you determining the `ID` for the final result?  Those values don't seem to match the sample data.

Comment: @Mihai the only DBMS that will parse for is MySQL and even there it is illogical and incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `id` column is actually not important in your expected result. In which case, you just need to do a grouping and a summation:

```
select Items, sum(Quantity) as TotalQty
from MyTable
group by Items
```